# The limit point in the definition of a limit of function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. When we define the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to x_0$ we require $x_0$ to be the limit point of $E$.

Why do we require $x_0$ to be the limit point of $E$?

*The definition says:* We say that $A=\lim \limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ **iff** $\forall \varepsilon>0$ $\exists \delta=\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ : $\forall x\in E$ with $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x)-A|<\varepsilon$.

**My thoughts:** If $x_0$ is the limit of point of $E$ then $\{x\in E:0<|x-x_0|<\delta\}\neq \varnothing$ for any $\delta>0$. Probably this is one of the reasons but I may be wrong!

But what if $x_0$ is not a limit of $E$? For example, let's take some function $f(x)$ defined on $\{0\}\cup (1,2)$, where $x_0=0$.

What difficulties do we have?

Would be thankful if someone provide detailed answer with examples.

Comment: $0$ is a limit point of your $E$

Comment: "A" limit point, not "the" limit point.

Comment: "Probably this is one of the reasons": This is exactly the reason. If we take your definition literally, every function would converge to all values simultaneously at a non-limit-point.

Comment: the for all $x$ ... part becomes vacuously true for any value of $A$.

Comment: In other words, the limit depends on the values next to the point and not on the value at the point itself. If the function has no values next to the point, no sensible definition can be made.

Comment: no. In your example ANY values in the codomain of $f$ is the limit of $f$ at $0$ in the weaker definition of limit. You can always select $\delta = 1/2$, as there is no $x$ in $(-1/2, 1/2) \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: A statement of the type $\forall x: \phi(x) \implies \psi(x)$ is vacuously true if $\phi(x)$ is false for every $x$.

Comment: @Stefan, yeah it should be "a" limit point. Sorry for that since English is not my native language. Exodd in the above comment said that $0$ is limit point of $E$. How come? If we take the $1/2$-nbhd of $0$ with removed point $0$ then it does not intersect $E$. So $0$ is not a limit point. What's wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Nothing. I think, Exodd had a different definition of "limit point" in mind.

Comment: @Stefan, above you said that ""Probably this is one of the reasons": This is exactly the reason. If we take your definition literally, every function would converge to all values simultaneously at a non-limit-point." And what's wrong in this definition? A bit unclear.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the definition, as long as you include the assumption that $x_0$ is a limit point. Or are you asking what is wrong with having a function converge to all values at once?

Comment: @Stefan, what is wrong if a function converge to all values simultaneously at a non-limit point of $E$? This is my question

Comment: @ZFR: There is no right or wrong. It is just not useful. Imagine everytime you in a theorem or proof that you need to exclude or discuss the case that $x_0$ not a limit point.

Comment: Maybe nothing, but at least the term $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)$ is only well-defined if there is a unique limit.

Answer (score 1):

The def'n is flawed. It implies that if $x_0$ is not a limit point of $E$ then $$A=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$$ is true for any and all $A,$ e.g. $0=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=1.$

If $S$ is a sentence and $\forall y\; (T)\;$ (or, respectively $\exists y\; (T)\;$) occurs in $S$, where $(T)$ is the rest of the sentence, then in the negation of $S$  this part will change to $\exists y (\neg T)\;$ (respectively $\forall y\;(\neg T)\;$).

So the def'n says $$A\ne \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) \text { iff } \exists e>0\;\forall d>0\; \exists x\, (0<|x-x_0|<d \land |f(x)-f(x_0)\ge e).$$ Now if $0<|x-x_0|<d$ then $f(x)$ does not exist unless $x\in E,$ so a consequence of the def'n is

$ A\ne \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\implies x_0$ is a limit point of $E,$

equivalently,

if $x_0$ is not a limit point of $E$ then $A=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x).$

The def'n should be amended by inserting "$x_0$ is a limit point of $E$ and" just after the bold-face "iff".

Comment: In some contexts it is convenient to also allow $f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ when $x_0$ is an isolated point of $E$.

Answer (score 1):

I like to work with the following definition of the limit of a function between metric spaces:

> Let $(X,d_{X})$ and $(Y,d_{Y})$ be metric spaces such that $f:X\to Y$ is a function. Consider as well that we are given a set $E\subseteq X$ such that $x_{0}\in X$ is an adherent point of $E$ and $L\in Y$. Then we say that $f$ converges to $L$ as $x$ approaches $x_{0}$ along $E$ iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds a $\delta > 0$ such that, for every $x\in E$,
> \begin{align*}
> d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta \Rightarrow d_{Y}(f(x),L) <\varepsilon
> \end{align*}

It is slightly different from your definition, because we demand that $d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta$ instead of $0 < d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \varepsilon$. However your definition can be considered a particular case from the definition I have mentioned. Indeed, it suffices to consider $E\backslash\{x_{0}\}$ and both of them are the same. The set $E$ tells us how we are approaching $x_{0}$.

Still, the answer to your question has not been given. More precisely, why do we need to consider $x_{0}\in X$ to be an adherent point of $E$? In order to answer it, remember that the set of adherent points of $E$ equals $\overline{E} = \text{int}(E)\cup\partial(E)$. Consequently, if $x\not\in\overline{E}$, then $x\in\text{ext}(E)$. This means there exists a positive real number $r > 0$ such that $B(x_{0},r)\cap E = \varnothing$. In other words, for a $\delta$ small enough $(\delta \leq r)$, there is no $x\in E$ such that $d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta$, which makes the definition of limit vacuous.

That's why we require $x_{0}\in X$ to be an adherent point of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, Heine's definition (that is equivalent to epsilon-delta definition) of the limit of a function may answer your question:

> For functions on the real line, one way to define the limit of a function is in terms of the limit of sequences. In this setting:
> $$\lim _{x\to x_0}f(x)=A$$
> if and only if for all sequences $x_{n}$ (with $x_{n} \not = x_0$, $\forall n$) converging to $x_0$ the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $A$.

Therefore, if $x_0$ would not be a limit point of $\mathcal{D}(f)$, then how would such $x_n$ exist?